# Having the values of x and y and the graph between them in Matlab, how to determine if the dataset is unstable?

Tags: matlab, physics, matlab-figure

I having several datasets comprising of the values `x` and `y`, and a graph plot between the two values for each dataset.

Having this information with me, how to find if the particular dataset results in unstable/stable system?
*(A function is stable if y remains bounded even after some x otherwise it is unstable. Please see the diagrams below for the difference.)*

My idea is to find the `max(y)` for few `x` at specific intervals. If the `max()` value increases as the `x` increases, the function is unstable.

Is there any flaw in this approach? Is there any better idea?

Here are the examples of a stable and unstable graph(system) respectively :

**Stable system :**
[image: Stable]

**Unstable system :**
[image: Unstable]

Comment: Can you show us what this function is?  It's hard to give you an answer when we can't see it.  Do you have some definition or heuristic that defines at what point you would consider something unstable?

Comment: I have added other details. Please check again.

Comment: If you know the period of your system, the `max` approach should work (just make sure to include at least one full period). But an even better result might be achieved with the function fitting toolbox, I think that should allow you to retrieve both the natural frequency and the poles of your underlying system.

Comment: Another solution would be to use the `findpeaks` function, and see if the maxima are increasing.

Comment: A numerical dataset is bounded by definition. Your question can only apply to a function from which the dataset has been generated. That means you need to find a model for your data. For that you need a class of possible models, together with a method of model selection.